# Is there a book which proves Euclid's propositions of geometry using Hilbert's (or similar) axioms?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is there a book which proves Euclid's propositions of geometry using Hilbert's (or similar) axioms? I'd like to see Euclid's propositions proved in as much the same order as possible but using Hilbert's axioms or something close to them.

Comment: You need only prove Euklid's axioms, don't you?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Hartshorne's wonderfull book does this.

Comment: Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometry: Development and History by Marvin Jay Greenberg does a fair bit of that.

Comment: The trouble with only proving Euclid's axioms is that Euclid's axioms have holes. So if that's all you prove then you will be missing various unstated axioms that Euclid's theorems also rely on. Hilbert's axioms are a culmination of a long history of identifying and plugging those holes.